# Admob AD Unit Via Firebase Remote Config

Tags: android, admob, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to put my ADMOB ads via Firebase Remote Config, so that i can change it remotely in case my admob account is somehow terminated

I have followed the tutorial for the remote implementation . But the problem that i am facing is with AndroidManifest.xml

```
******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************
```

I believe i should insert my App ID like this

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

But i don't want to use a static AdMob App ID as i mentioned before 
So how can i insert the value programmatically

Thank you

Comment: I want to do the same thing. Any progress?

Comment: Hi. Did you solve? I want to do the same